# How to Memoize Function

Tags: python, memoization

The problem is that there is a number pyramid and you're trying to find the largest sum by "slithering" down the pyramid.

I did a basic "memoization" technique by making an array and passing it in with every function call. Obviously, this isn't ideal because the array is of fixed size and I can't have the array depend on the initial pyramid size because the optional parameter must be independent of that. I'm not sure how I can make the array size depend on the size of the pyramid without hardcoding it in or explicitly asking for the initial array and the initial size when the function is called.

```
def LSD2(pyramid, m = 0, n = 0, L = []):
    if len(L) == 0:
      L = [[None]*1000 for i in range(1000)]
    if len(pyramid) == 0:
      return 0

    else:
      if L[n][m] != None:
        return L[n][m]
      elif L[n-1][m] != None and L[n-1][m-1] != None:
        return max(pyramid[n][m] + max(L[n-1][m], L[n-1][m-1]))
      L[n][m] = pyramid[0][m] + max(LSD2(pyramid[1:], m, n + 1, L), LSD2(pyramid[1:], m+1, n + 1, L))
    return L[n][m]
```

Comment: Python does not have arrays, it has lists and they are not fixed size.

Comment: If `m` and `n` are rows and columns respectively, you can initialize a `m` by `n` array like `l = [[None] * n for _ in range(m)]`

Answer (score 0):

As @KlausD. points out, Python only has dynamic arrays called `list`s. You can add and remove elements with `.append` and `.remove` respectively. That said, a `dict` with tuple keys is probably a better choice given your use case. So your code would become:

```
def LSD2(pyramid, m = 0, n = 0, L = {}):
    if len(pyramid) == 0:
      return 0

    if (n, m) in L:
      return L[(n, m)]
    elif L.get((n-1, m), None) and L.get((n-1, m-1), None):
      return max(pyramid[n][m] + max(L[(n-1, m)], L[(n-1, m-1)]

    L[(n, m)] = pyramid[0][m] + max(LSD2(pyramid[1:], m, n + 1, L), LSD2(pyramid[1:], m+1, n + 1, L))  
    return L[(n, m)]
```

Comment: As a note, just because lists are dynamic does not mean you cannot initialize one with a predetermined size.